# PySpark sql CASE fails

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

i've encoutered strange behaviour when working with PySpark sqlContext. The problem is best ilustrated in the code below.

I am checking the value of COLUMN in simple case statement. However WHEN is not triggered even though the condition checks TRUE and always jumps to ELSE. Am I doing something wrong with the syntax here?

```
dataTest = spark.sql("""SELECT 
COLUMN > 1,
CASE COLUMN 
    WHEN COLUMN > 1 THEN 1
    ELSE COLUMN 
    END AS COLUMN_2,
COLUMN
FROM TABLE
""")


dataTest.sort(col("COLUMN").desc()).show(5, False)

+---------------+-------------+---------+ 
|COLUMN >1      |COLUMN_2     |COLUMN   | 
+---------------+-------------+---------+ 
|true           |14           |14       | 
|true           |5            |5        | 
|true           |4            |4        | 
|true           |3            |3        | 
|true           |2            |2        | 
+---------------+-------------+---------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the syntax, try:

```
SELECT 
COLUMN > 1,
CASE WHEN COLUMN > 1 THEN 1
     ELSE COLUMN 
     END AS COLUMN_2,
COLUMN
FROM TABLE
```

Notice there's no *COLUMN* between *CASE* and *WHEN* keywords.

Comment: Well I am going to jump from my window right away, such a basic mistake. Thanks for clearing it up!